# Support of measure of preimage

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(Y, B(Y))$ be a measurable space where Y is a metric space and B(Y) the Borel Sigma algebra generated by the standard topology on Y.

Let $f: (X, B(X)) \to (Y, B(Y)) $ and let 
$$ v: B(Y) \to [0, + \infty]$$
$$ A \to m(f^{-1}(A))$$

(where X is a separable metric space and $m$ a measure on the measurable space $(X, B(X))$.

My question is simple: What is the support of $v$?

Comment: What's the support of $m$? Is $f$ onto, etc.?

Comment: supp(m) is X \ $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ denotes a (maximal) element.

Comment: maximal element? Under what order? $X$ is merely metric.

Comment: Under measurable spaces. (and, B(X) is of course the Borel sigma algebra ).

Comment: The question cannot be answered without some further  assumptions on $f$. If you are not even assuming that $f$ is continuous there is no hope of describing the support of $v$ in terms of support of $m$.

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous bijection then support of $v$ is the image under $f$ of the support of $m$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right, thank you for this comment!

Comment: Is $f$ at least measurable? It must be, really, to make $v$ well-defined.